# Ext JS disabled Panel mask Opacity

Tags: extjs

How can I control to opacity of a disabled panel with a mask.
I would like to disable to the panel (meaning It will be touchable) and leave its opacity as is.
Thx

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can create your own CSS style sheet that overrides ExtJS's default style sheet for disabled items.  In `ext-all.css`, there are several style configurations for the `.x-item-disabled` class that you can take a look at.  For example, they specify the opacity for toolbar button icons like so:

```
.x-toolbar .x-item-disabled .x-btn-icon {
    opacity: .35;
    -moz-opacity: .35;
    filter: alpha(opacity=35);
}
```

So you'll have to look up what class your panel belongs to and construct a style sheet that includes specification for your particular selectors.

[CSS Syntax (Wikipedia)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CSS)

Answer (score 4):

I would recommend to whoever lands on this post, to create a class for the panel disabled state in your own css file and then configure the panel disabled state class as follows, so you will only affect the desired panel and not the entire application:

In your CSS

```
.my-disabled-panel {
     opacity: .35;
    -moz-opacity: .35;
    filter: alpha(opacity=35);
 }
```

And in the panel config...

```
Ext.create('Ext.panel.Panel', {    
    [...],
    disabledCls: 'my-disabled-panel',
    [...]
}
```